# Playing WPF music as a resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I've searched a lot, but nothing has helped so far.
I've created a Folder in my WPF Project, placed a song there, and now I am trying to play it.

```
    class Songs
    {
        static MediaPlayer Player = new MediaPlayer();
        public static void PlaySong()
        {
            Player.Open(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Songs/RandomSong.mp3"));
            Player.Play();
        }
    }
```

This, however does not produce any sound. I don't want to have a physical path location, because the problem is the directory changes from computer to computer

Is it possible to play it as a resource?

Comment: Have you set the Build Action of the file to Resource?

Comment: I have. The above code doesn't give errors, but does not produce any sound

Comment: Take a look at the different options in the answers to the original question.

Comment: I've tried a few different steps. It turns out that, MediaPlayer cannot play from resources but SoundPlayer can, that's weird, but at least this works now.

Comment: Actually, SoundPlayer is very very limited, it's not good. It doesn't support resume or pause